# Is there liking query operator ,join query In "playhouse extensions to peewee"?

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I can use total CRUD by the MySQLDatabase that imported "from peewee import *"

But when I see the "playhouse,extensions to peewee".
I prefre this CRUD by the DataSet that improted "from playhouse.dataset import DataSet".
It  seems likes the "pymongo" syntax,   emmmmmm. It is so convenient!!

But, I can't find the detail query in the document。
such as  query operator, join query.......

like the following example:
prepare data in database:

```
id name
1  Tom
```

I want to find the name contains 'om'   in database.
by the  "from peewee import *"  way:

```
Owner.select().where(Owner.name.contains('om'))
```

by the  "from playhouse.dataset import DataSet"  way:

```
owner = db['owner']
owner.find(??????????)     #  how to use contains
```

---

finally I want to know that  what scene I should use the DataSet's  CRUD ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dataset` API is designed for only the simplest kinds of usage. It is never intended to be a full replacement for the expressiveness of SQL.

dataset is designed to allow you to easily import/export/explore data, or work with it in a simple manner.